Apache Avro C++ Seg Fault
I'm trying to use the Avro C++ library. I want to create a GenericDatum instance, but I'm getting a segfault with the following code.
avro_read.cc
#include <fstream>
#include <avro/GenericDatum.hh>
#include <avro/ValidSchema.hh>
#include <avro/Compiler.hh>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Read in and compile schema.
  std::ifstream in("schema.avsc");
  avro::ValidSchema valid_schema;
  avro::compileJsonSchema(in, valid_schema);

  // Create a generic datum (segfaults).
  avro::GenericDatum datum(valid_schema); 
  return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(repro CXX)

find_package(unofficial-avro-cpp CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(avro_read avro_read.cc)
target_link_libraries(avro_read PRIVATE unofficial::avro-cpp::avrocpp)

vcpkg.json
{
  "name": "segfault-repro",
  "version-string": "unversioned",
  "description": "A simple repro for the avro GenericDatum segfault",
  "dependencies": [
    "avro-cpp"
  ]
}

schema.avsc
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "__root__",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "total",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "long"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I'm using CMake and Vcpkg to compile and the following commands:
cmake -S . -B .build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
cmake --build .build
.build/avro_read 

I tried running gdb (gdb .build/avro_read, but didn't get anything useful
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555ecd70 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555555ecd70 in ?? ()
#1  0x000055555556b46d in main ()

Then I ran valgrind --leak-check=full .build/avro_read
==2398834== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2398834== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2398834== Using Valgrind-3.20.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2398834== Command: .build/avro_read
==2398834== 
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF1 0x60 0x3E 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10 0x7F
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=NONE
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==2398834== Invalid read of size 1
==2398834==    at 0x4DC7EC0: ???
==2398834==    by 0x4DC60DF: ???
==2398834==    by 0x7: ???
==2398834==  Address 0x1b is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2398834== 
==2398834== 
==2398834== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2398834==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1B
==2398834==    at 0x4DC7EC0: ???
==2398834==    by 0x4DC60DF: ???
==2398834==    by 0x7: ???
==2398834==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2398834==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2398834==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2398834==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2398834==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2398834== 
==2398834== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2398834==     in use at exit: 84,688 bytes in 40 blocks
==2398834==   total heap usage: 123 allocs, 83 frees, 97,888 bytes allocated
==2398834== 
==2398834== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2398834==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2398834==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2398834==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2398834==    still reachable: 84,688 bytes in 40 blocks
==2398834==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2398834== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==2398834== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==2398834== 
==2398834== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==2398834== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    2398834 segmentation fault  valgrind --leak-check=full .build/avro_read

Update:
The avro code has an include for any/boost any depending on the C++ version. https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/e932c9453be7b36e8874fe92edb3710beef4e47c/lang/c%2B%2B/api/GenericDatum.hh#L27-L31.
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#include <any>
#else
#include "boost/any.hpp"
#endif

When I compile with C++ 14, I get no segfault:
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

but when I use C++ 17 or C++20, I segfault
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

I think one of the any_cast is called on a nullptr and segfaulting.

If you have valgrind you may have Address and Undefiend behaviour sanitizers. Turn them on and see if they give any useful diagnostics.

I enabled both in cmake using target_compile_options(avro_read PUBLIC -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address) and target_link_options(avro_read PUBLIC -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address) and now get ```==2408036==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x604000000710 (pc 0x604000000710 bp 0x7f7896400000 sp 0x7ffffb2bcea8 T0)
==2408036==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==2408036==Hint: PC is at a non-executable region. Maybe a wild jump?
#0 0x604000000710  ()
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.``` when I run the program.

I'm going to use C++ 14, which compiles without segfaulting.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
